# The Amplify CLI can NOT find command: pull

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-amplify

I have just installed amplify cli through the command:

npm install @aws-amplify/cli

It mentions it has installed version 4.2.0.

Following the directions of the document below, I tried to run an "Amplify Pull" command to rearrange my files based on the contents on the cloud:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart

However it tells me that The Amplify CLI can NOT find command:  pull

Is it correct? Which command should I run instead of this one?

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm you ran `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` (note the `-g` flag)? Otherwise, you may have an older global `amplify`, while your local project has the newer `amplify`.

1. `which amplify` should return something like `/usr/local/bin/amplify`
2. `amplify --version` should return `4.2.0`

Comment: Thanks! I did it, it installed correctly but when I type "amplify pull" it still states Amplify doesn't know this command...

Comment: Shoot.  I'm not sure what to do.  Tell you what, can you reach out to me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/ericclemmons) and we'll do a screen share?

Comment: You should make sure that your amplify version is 4.2.0. I faced the same issue and fixed it by running npm i @aws-amplify/cli@4.6.0 -g

Comment: If you don't specify the version it will automatically download the latest. Btw it solved the problem thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like changing the F (capital) to f (lowercase) solved my issue:

`amplify remove Function`

The Amplify CLI can NOT find command:  remove Function

Scanning for plugins...

`amplify remove function`

No resources added for this category

p.s (Function is the name of the category)